# Alias apache with requested URL?

Tags: apache, alias

If I write in the settings:
Alias /blog2/ "/path_to_other/www/"
The script will be run from the root directory as / (as root)
But I need it with requested url -> /blog2
Now, to get 
/blog2 
I need to write:
/blog2/blog2
Option Alias /blog2/ "/path_to/www/blog2/" is not working

I have two folders: 1. Main folder with index.php 2. Another folder with index.php. All requests should go to folder N1, except /blog2/../.. But script in folder N2 should get the full url -> /blog2/../.. I set Alias /blog2 "/path_to/www/blog2" and now it gets /../.. (without leading /blog2). Yes, I tried RewriteRule ^/blog2 /blog2/blog2 [NC,L] Not working too

Comment: What does it do instead of work as expected? Remove the trailing slashes and try it as `Alias /blog2 "/path_to/www/blog2"` then restart Apache and I would expect it to work as you intend. It's unclear why you have `Option` there. That shouldn't be present for an `Alias` directive.

Comment: I need to chage the script folder for url, but i need to save the url too, so "/path_to/www/blog2" just set folder, what I need, is "/path_to/www" as folder (where is index.php)+ /blog2 as URL

Comment: Please edit your post above to include exact input and output URLs together with the paths on disk they should load. It sounds like you could use a combination of `Alias` and `RewriteRule` to compose the behavior you need.

Comment: I have two folders: 1. Main folder with index.php 2. Another folder with index.php. All requests should go to folder N1, except /blog2/../.. But script in folder N2 should get the full url -> /blog2/../.. I set Alias /blog2 "/path_to/www/blog2" and now it gets /../.. (without leading /blog2). Yes, I tried RewriteRule    ^/blog2 /blog2/blog2 [NC,L] Not working too

Comment: Please edit your original post to include that information with  as much detail as possible, use full example URLs and file paths.